# How to create this type of page in LaTex

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

I want to create sort of repetitive pattern in an A4 page with minimal margin. As a sample image, given with this text.
[image]

But I am not getting how to do this. Any hint is appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Refer the `tcolorbox` documentation, and refer `page number 309`

Comment: Can you find a more descriptive title for your post rather then using "How can I make [this]?"

Answer (score 6):

I would employ `tikz` with two `\foreach` loops. Here's the example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\tikzset{
  every node/.style = {
    draw,
    red,
    text = black,
    font = \large,
    line width = 1.6pt,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width = 3cm,
    minimum height = 1cm,
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yo using \y*1.25] in {0,...,19} {
      \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xo using \x*3.75, evaluate=\d using int(\x+5*\y+1)] in {0,...,4} {
        \node at (\xo,-\yo) {The day \d}; }}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT. Here is a slightly altered code, which now generates paragraphs with rows of nodes, which will continue to the other page if necessary. They are copied inside `\foreach` so you can change how many rows you need.

A couple of things.
Nodes do not add line breaks nor do they accept `\newline`, `\\` or `\par` by default, unless you specify text width. I also added small padding with `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`.

The horizontal space is stretchable and depends on size of your labels. Vertical space is controlled by `\lineskip` which is equal to 1pt by default. I changed that to `1em`. At this point, I have to make a comment. In this example, content of paragraphs very likely exceed a standard paragraph height, and LaTeX adds a minimum distance stored in `\lineskip` to avoid overlapping. I *exploit* this fact and change the min space to `1em`. This is almost certainly not going to work in other examples.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style = {
    draw, red, line width = 1.6pt, rounded corners,
    text = black, font = \large, align = center,
    text width = 4cm,
    inner xsep = 3pt, inner ysep = 6pt,
  }
}
\newsavebox\textlabel
\NewDocumentCommand\TL{s}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\hfill}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node {%
      Multiple line sample
      \par Second line
      \par Third line
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
\setlength\lineskip{1em}%   % minimum vertical space

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {\par\TL* \TL \TL \TL};
\end{document}
```

Note, this can also be sorted with `longtable`.

Comment: One of an excellent suggestion :-)

Comment: Thank you. But how to add something bellow to "The day" in the same box? {The day \d \\Another line} is not working

Comment: And how to continue after 100 in another page

Comment: @TanmoyPati I have added an update to my answer. The new code should do the job (I hope).

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks. It was a matter of putting a few commands together.

Answer (score 3):

MadyYuvi already pointed you to a suitable package, I'll simply expand on this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colframe=red,colback=white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
        % I think you can imagine how to go on...
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit: Advancing the number.

As requested in a comment, you can advance the number displayed in the box. The simplest way is of course to advance the number manually, so

```
\begin{mybox}The Day 1\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}The Day 2\end{mybox}
```

and so on. This is of course not the best way to go.

Then you have the idea of adding a counter which does the numbering for you, see MadyYuvi's answer (+1). This will still require to repeat the code `\begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}` over and over again.

This is why IMHO the best solution involves a for loop (`forloop` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tcolorbox,forloop}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colframe=red,colback=white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \newcounter{boxcounter}
        \forloop{boxcounter}{1}{\value{boxcounter} < 25}{%
            \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        }
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result with advancing numbers]
BTW this answer is completely applicable if you need more than one page of these boxes.

Comment: It is quite nice and simple. But how to continue with integer? Not 1 at all the boxes

Answer (score 1):

Per the `OP`'s comment, just added a `counter` in @Οὖτις answer,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tcolorbox}

\newcounter{boxcounter}%
\setcounter{boxcounter}{0}%
\renewcommand{\theboxcounter}{\arabic{boxcounter}}%

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{code={\refstepcounter{boxcounter}},colframe=red,colback=white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}The Day \theboxcounter\end{mybox}
        % I think you can imagine how to go on...
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]